# Função não executa sem setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timeout

Estou tendo um problema ao executar uma função ao clicar no `icheck`. No caso, a função só é chamada caso eu dê um `setTimeout` de 1 milisegundo, menos do que isso ou sem `timeout` a função não é executada. Como eu posso fazer para executar essa função sem utilizar `timeout`?

```
vm.selecionaFiltros = function(){
    $('.marcas').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
        radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    });

    $timeout(function() {
        $('.marcas').on('ifChanged', function (event) {
            console.log('1');
        });
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: você executa todo esse trecho toda vez que o usuário clica no checkbox? .iCheck transforma os elementos em objetos iCheck e normalmente só é usado uma vez, logo após a página carregar. Além disso, se é para detectar o click você deveria usar os eventos ifClicked ou ifToggled.

Comment: Olá @EduardoMoreira, eu testei utilizando o ifClicked e Toggled e removi a inicialização o iCheck de dentro da função, mas o meu problema persiste, já que o problema não é no iCheck, é no tempo de rendenização do site, que não consegue pegar o evento ao clicar.
A função selecionaFiltros é chamada após terminar o ng-repeat da listagem de filtros.

Comment: @BernardoKowacic a função `vm.selecionaFiltros` é chamada automaticamente ou precisa ter alguma interação do usuário? Exemplo, clicar em um `checkbox`?

Comment: Olá @CelsomTrindade, então, a função é chamada quando carrega a página, automáticamente. Atualmente eu tirei a inicialização de dentro da função, deixei apenas a parte que verifica se foi marcado ou não.

Comment: @BernardoKowacic baseado nisso vou tentar uma resposta que eu imagino que seja o problema.. Conversamos mais ao longo dos comentários ali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se essa função `vm.selecionaFiltros` é chamada de modo automático, o possível problema é que ela esteja acontecendo fora do escopo do `AngularJs`.

**O que isso significa?**

Significa que o `digest cycle` já passou, logo as mudanças não serão aplicadas. `digest cycle` é um processo do `AngularJs` (também conhecido como *dirty checking*) que faz a comparação de todos os *bindings* através dos `watchers` (`{{meuEscopo}}` ou `ng-bind="meuEscopo"` - cada elemento desse em sua view gera um novo `watcher`) para verificar se aquele dado sofreu alteração e, se sim, atualizar a `view` com esse novo valor.

Se a sua função é executada **após** o `digest cycle` significa que por mais que as mudanças ocorram o `AngularJs` ainda não "sabe" disso.

**Quando um `digest cycle` é disparado?**

Sempre são disparados quando a aplicação carrega ou através de interações com funções do próprio AngularJS, por exemplo, `ngClick`, `ngChange`, `ngBlur`, etc.. Ou, dentro de um `controller` ou `directive`, através do uso de `$timeout` (que é o que você está fazendo) e `$interval` e, por fim, através de uma chamada manual, explicado melhor abaixo.

**Como resolver?**

O modo de resolver isso seria chamando manualmente o `digest cycle`.

Existem 2 métodos de se obter o mesmo resultado final:

- `$scope.$digest()`
- `$scope.$apply()`

Ambos são semelhantes e irão lhe dar o mesmo resultado final. Porém o `$scope.$apply()` irá disparar o evento `$rootScope.$digest()` que afeta todos os escopos e seus elementos *child* enquanto o `$scope.$digest()` afeta apenas o escopo local e seus elementos *child*, lhe dando uma melhor perfomance, já que não irá afetar a aplicação como um todo.

Exemplo simples, supondo que na mesma view que esse `ng-repeat` você possua um `directive` que mostre o clima, ele não tem ligação alguma com essa lista e possui seu próprio escopo, uma vez que ele vem de um `directive`. Se você chamar `$scope.$digest()`, o `digest cycle` não irá verificar os `watchers` que pertencem a ele, logo você tem mais performance. Mas se você chamar o `$scope.$apply()`, como ele irá disparar o `$rootScope.$digest()` ao invés do `$scope.$digest()` - ou seja, o ciclo global, aquele directive de clima e todos os seus watchers e *child* também serão validados pelo ciclo.

**Quando usar um ou outro?**

Se você tem certeza que a função chamada só irá afetar valores que estão dentro desse escopo, chame o `$scope.$digest()`. Mas se você sabe que a interação com essas funções podem interferir em escopos que estão fora do atual, use o `$scope.$apply()`.

Exemplo: Supondo que essa lista de `ng-repeat` seja para selecionar qual o tipo de temperatura é exibido no `directive`. *Celsius*, *Kelvin* ou *Fahrenheit*, então se eu clicar em um desses elementos do `ng-repeat`, eu preciso alterar um elemento fora do meu escopo, logo, chamo o `$scope.$apply()`.

Sendo assim, seu código ficaria assim:

```
vm.selecionaFiltros = function(){
    $('.marcas').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
        radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    });

    $('.marcas').on('ifChanged', function (event) {
        console.log('1');
        $scope.$digest(); //aqui
    });

    $scope.$digest(); //ou aqui
}
```

Se quiser, ainda pode remover a declaração da função usando o `vm` e usar uma função `JS` simples.

```
function selecionaFiltros() {
    [...]
}

//chamada da função
selecionaFiltros();
```

O `vm` na frente serve para executar uma função que é chamada através da *view*, com `ng-click`, `ng-blur`, etc..

---

*Nota*: Apenas para lembrar, como você está usando a `syntax` de `vm`, precisa injetar o `$scope` antes de poder usá-lo.

Comment: Olá @CelsomTrindade, eu coloquei o $scope.$digest(); dentro da função do ifChanged e não aconteceu nada, continuou sem funcionar, tentei colocar em na linha de baixo, mas aí deu erro dizendo que $digest não é uma função. Tentei adicionar o $digest no inject do módulo e na chamada da função e deu erro também. Estou injetando o $scope  para usá-lo. Com o $apply ocorreu a mesma coisa.

Comment: @BernardoKowacic o que você precisa injetar é o $scope, não o $digest ou o $apply. Caso ainda assim não dê certo, monte um fiddle ou plunkr onde o problema possa ser reproduzido para poder analisar melhor.