# Destruir função AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, flexslider

Possuo uma página em meu projeto que contém diversas categorias e em cada categoria, possui um Flexslider com as imagens.
Cada categoria é exibida uma vez e ao clicar em outra, a anterior é oculta e a clicada é exibida, esquema parecido com Tabs.

Preciso que quando eu clico em outra categoria, ele destrua a função do Flexslider inciada na categoria anterior e seja executada nesta categoria.

Segue o que eu fiz até agora, porém sem sucesso:

Função que inicia Flexslider:

```
vm.sliderCol = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.sliderCol').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Função que inseri no botão da categoria:

```
vm.clicou = function(){
    $('.sliderCol').flexslider("destroy");
    console.log('destruiu');
    setTimeout(function () {
        vm.sliderCol();
        console.log('iniciou');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Até então, tentei destruir o Flexslider, não sei se há algum método de parar de executar a função e iniciá-la, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: O que a função `vm.sliderCol()` faz? Você sabe se ela está funcionando? Pois dentro do AngularJs usar `setTimeout` não é o método certo. O correto é substituí-lo por `$timeout`.

Comment: Sim, substituí por $timeout. A função vm.sliderCol inicia o Flexslider, referente a minha resposta abaixo, ao clicar em uma categoria, eu destruo o flex e inicio novamente com a função, pois como está como display none em uma tab, ele não pega altura da div e por isso não estava sendo exibido. Porém destruindo a função do flex e iniciando novamente ele pega a altura, pois ao iniciar a tab já está aberta.

Comment: Entendi. Mas então, por que está usando um `$timeout` com apenas 100 de _delay_? Sei que muitas pessoas usam ele para poder "ativar" as mudanças dentro do meio `Angular`. Seria esse o seu caso? Se sim, talvez seja melhor usar `$digest()`, não seria o seu caso?

Comment: Boa dica, vou pesquisar sobre e implementar :D

Comment: Dê uma lida nessa minha resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139220/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-executa-sem-settimeout/140117#140117 Trata bem essa questão =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o ng-click em cada categoria jogando a função, consegui destruir o slider e iniciá-lo novamente com a seguinte função:

```
vm.clicou = function(){
    $('.sliderCol').flexslider("destroy");
    $('.sliderCol').removeData("flexslider");
    setTimeout(function () {
        vm.sliderCol();
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Interessante. Uma sugestão de melhoria seria não usar o `setTimeout`. Pelo o que vi no seu código, parece apenas que quer executar a função. Sugiro utilizar o `$digest()` para o angular executar novamente todo o ciclo e obter as mudanças entre model e view.

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão o `FlexSlider` tem o atributo `slideshow: true`, nesse caso, pra parar a execução terá que setar esse valor para false. Veja como ficará:

```
vm.clicou = function(){
  $('.sliderCol').flexslider({
    slideshow: false
  });
  console.log('destruiu');
};
```

Abraço e espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Boa, eu encontrei a solução, é semelhante, vou postá-la.